# Can´t parse booleans using telegraf and kafka

Tags: boolean, kafka-consumer-api, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am trying to connect an InfluxDB database with kafka so that the data received by kafka is consumed by InfluxDB. For this I am using telegraf, an InfluxDB plugin.

The goal is to get a json similar to this:

```
"features": {
 "feat1": {
  "properties": {
    "value": 37.47996355008505,
    "unit": "mm"
   }
 },
 "feat2": {
  "properties": {
    "value": true
   }
 },
 "feat3": {
  "properties": {
    "value": 75.20817161095022,
    "unit": "kW"
   }
 }
```

The result I get is the following:

```
value_feat1_properties_value=78.74519381419572,value_feat3_properties_value=98.36521109165896 1689340243356300699
```

I've tried using the v2 version of the json parser and I've also tried putting the name of the boolean variable in the json_string_field section. Any suggestions on how to fix this.